# error while running function

Tags: java, junit

Hi im trying to run my function and test it thought the junit test but i can't figure out why my junit tests are failing. im sure that the function that i wrote works. This is homework if anyone is wondering .

here is the test

```
@Test
public void test4() {
    lst1.removeAll(3);
    assertEquals(8, lst1.size());
    assertEquals(false, lst1.contains(3));
    lst1.removeAll(6);
    assertEquals(5, lst1.size());
    assertEquals(false, lst1.contains(6));
    lst1.removeAll(5);
    assertEquals(3, lst1.size());
    lst1.removeAll(4);
    assertEquals(2, lst1.size());
    lst1.removeAll(7);
    assertEquals(1, lst1.size());
    lst1.removeAll(8);
    assertEquals(0, lst1.size());
}
```

here is the code

```
public void removeAll( E x ) {
      first = first.next;
       if (first.data == x ) {
           first = first.next;   
       }
       Node curr = first;
       Node fut = curr.next ; 
       while ( fut!= null) {
            if (fut.data == x ) {
                curr.next = fut.next;               
            }
         curr=curr.next;
         fut=fut.next; 
       }
    assert check();
}
```

set up of the junit

```
public class MyListTest {
    private MyList<Integer> lst0;
    private MyList<Integer> lst1;
    private Integer[] a;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        lst0 = new MyList<Integer>();

        a = new Integer[] {3,4,3,5,6,8,6,6,7,5};
        lst1 = new MyList<Integer>();
        for(Integer x: a) {
            lst1.add(x);
        }
}
```

Size method

```
public int size() {
   return sz;
}
```

Main method

```
public class MyList<E extends Comparable< E>> implements Iterable<E> {
   private Node first;
   private int sz;

   public MyList() {
      first = null;
      sz = 0;
      assert check();
   }
}
```

check method

```
private boolean check()
{
    if (first == null && sz != 0) return false;
    if (sz == 0 && first != null) return false;
    if (sz == 1 && (first == null || first.next != null)) return false;
    if (sz > 1 && (first == null || first.next == null)) return false;

    int count = 0;
    Node p = first;
    while(p != null) {
        count++;
        p = p.next;
    }

    if (count != sz) {
        System.out.printf("count = %d, sz = %d\n", count, sz);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Where's the error message?

Comment: what is `first`? where do you set up the data you work with in your test?

Comment: at the assert check();  and lst1.removeAll(3); im not sure why. first is the first link in the linked list

Comment: where in your `removeAll` method do you expect something to be actually removed

Comment: the remove all is suppose to remove all of x element in the linked list.

Comment: i assumed that the method is supposed to do that, but where is the code that actually does it? at least not in the code you showed us...

Comment: doesn't the removeall do that?

Comment: well you switch the "link targets" in your list so the elemtents to be removed get skipped (but leaves those elements in an undefined state. take care of this later). Can you show us your `size()` and `check()` methods?

Comment: am i taking the links away or what am i doing in the code?

Comment: tell me. It's your code :D Tell me what was your intend when you wrote this code or did you just copy it?

Comment: i was playing around with it till i got the result that i wanted. i wanted to create it so that i goes to every link and check if it had x and if it had x to unlink it. but now when i look at the check function it looks like the links are still there

Comment: create a simple test, where you create an instance of your list, add a single number, call removeAll with that number and assert that your list is empty and size is 0. change your code until it passes this test. do nothing else till the bar goes green. then extend the test: add other numbers, remove different numbers and check the size and if there are really no elements with that number in your list. if this does not work, change your code until it passes the test

Answer (score 0):

If you are totally stuck you might consider starting over from scratch and go your way again with smaller yet safer steps.

Start with a simple test:

```
@Test
public void testConstruct() {
    MyNewList<Integer> myNewList = new MyNewList<Integer>();
    assertNotNull(myNewList);
    assertEquals(0, myNewList.size());
}
```

now write **just enough** code in `MyNewList` to pass the test - do **not** think of complicated structure, the most simple solution will suffice for now - even `return 0;` for `size()` is okay.

If your code finally passes the test you can write another one:

```
@Test
public void testAdd() {
    MyNewList<Integer> myNewList = new MyNewList<Integer>();
    myNewList.add(5);
    assertEquals(1, myNewList.size());
}
```

Again implement just enough code to pass **both** tests. Once you succeed alter the test to check if your solution also works with other parameters:

```
@Test
public void testAdd() {
    MyNewList<Integer> myNewList = new MyNewList<Integer>();
    myNewList.add(5);
    assertEquals(1, myNewList.size());
    myNewList.add(7);
    assertEquals(2, myNewList.size());
}
```

Now you can trust that your `add()` method and decide what to do next: Take a short rest and clean up your code or organize the internal structure of you class, or march on to the next destination of your journey?

When you finally go on you have to solve the next puzzle:

```
@Test
public void testRemoveAll() {
    MyNewList<Integer> myNewList = new MyNewList<Integer>();
    myNewList.add(5);
    myNewList.add(5);
    myNewList.add(7);
    myNewList.add(3);

    assertEquals(4, myNewList.size());
    myNewList.removeAll(3);
    assertEquals(3, myNewList.size());
}
```

Now again write just enough code to pass **all** tests. For now you may even implement your method this way:

```
public void removeAll(T element) {
    size--;
}
```

This would be could since it completely fulfils the requirements the above test describes. Now let us confront you method to a tougher check and alter the test:

```
@Test
public void testRemoveAll() {
    MyNewList<Integer> myNewList = new MyNewList<Integer>();
    myNewList.add(5);
    myNewList.add(5);
    myNewList.add(7);
    myNewList.add(3);

    assertEquals(4, myNewList.size());
    myNewList.removeAll(3);
    assertEquals(3, myNewList.size());
    myNewList.removeAll(5);
    assertEquals(1, myNewList.size());
}
```

If you chose a trivial solution earlier, you might be "in trouble" now ;) So think about your `removeAll()` method again and extend its code until it passes the tests again.
Once you have this done you can rest assured that you code works.

If you change something in your class run your tests again to see if something is broken.

If requirements toward the way your methods have to work change - change your tests to reflect the new requirements and run them again.

At a first glance this might seem very tedious but once you have a solid fondation of tests set up you can always say: "My code **does** work exactly how it should"